# Persistent Store in Java Given Runtime Store

Tags: java, stored-procedures, blackberry, singleton, persistence

I am trying to create a persistent and shared variable that will keep track of the number of notifications available to the user in a Blackberry app. This number is showed on the home screen and  should be kept even after the device is turned off until they check the application themselves, then the number is reset. I have been using a singleton to share the variable between the background process and the UI app itself below:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.RuntimeStore;

public class IconManager {
    private static IconManager _instance;
    private static final long GUID = 0xab4dd61c5d004c18L;
    private int iconCount;

    // constructor
    private IconManager() {
        iconCount = 0;
    }

    public static IconManager getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = (IconManager) RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().get(GUID);
            if (_instance == null) {
                IconManager singleton = new IconManager();

                RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().put(GUID, singleton); 
                _instance = singleton;
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public int getCount() {             
        return iconCount;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {      
        iconCount = count;
    }
}
```

I have been mainly using this site to try to figure out the Persistent store portion: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Storing-persistent-data/ta-p/442747

Is there an alternative to implement the persistent store given the above runtimestore? I was originally thinking of using code from the Blackberry example, but I'm confused on how to do this. From another thread user *mparizeau* wrote the following:

```
persistentCount = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xdec6a67096f833cL); 
synchronized (persistentCount) { 
    if (persistentCount.getContents() == null) { 
        persistentCount.setContents(new StoreInfo());
        persistentCount.commit(); 
    } 
}  
_data = (StoreInfo)persistentCount.getContents();
```

Now when you want to update it and save to the PersistentStore you can have something like:

```
_data.incElement();
synchronized(persistentCount) {
    persistentCount.setContents(_data);
    persistentCount.commit();
}
```

Could this be used in the above code somehow? I am extremely new to java and BB development so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you need exactly? specify clearly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use RunTimeStore, since you want to the information to persist even after the device is turned off.  From [this page](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Runtime_store_510466_11.jsp)

> The runtime store is not persistent. When you restart the BlackBerry
>   device, the data in the runtime store clears.

Try something like this:

```
public class IconManager {
    private static IconManager _instance;
    private final long GUID = 0xab4dd61c5d004c18L;
    private PersistentObject store;
    private int iconCount;

    private IconManager() {
        store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(GUID);
        synchronized(store) {
            if(store.getContents() == null) {
                store.setContents(new Integer(0));
                store.commit();
            }
        }
        iconCount = ((Integer)store.getContents()).intValue();
    }

    public static IconManager getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new IconManager();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public int getCount() {             
        return iconCount;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {      
        iconCount = count;
        synchronized(store) {
            store.setContents(new Integer(iconCount));
            store.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the help! The code compiles perfectly but only if I change the iconCount declaration to static. Now I had an issue before where putting static on that declaration wouldn't make the code work, and unfortunately the iconCount variable isn't saved in this case either. I THINK it might have something to do with iconCount being changed to static in order to compile. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: Also from the code above wouldn't the singleton need to be stored somehow? Because I thought the singleton is what keeps the variable synced between two events, so wouldn't taking that out destroy the relationship between event 1 and event 2 which share the common variable?

Comment: Oops, it actually should have been static in this case. However I just realized since you're using it as a singleton you actually don't need it to be static, you should be able to move the stuff in the static initializer to the constructor.  I'll update the code to reflect this.

Comment: As far as I understand it you just want the iconCount variable to be stored, so the singleton isn't "stored" per se.  What will happen is that the first time getInstance is called on your singleton it will go to the constructor and load the value of iconCount from the PersistentStore.  Whenever you call setCount the value of iconCount will be saved to the PersistentStore.  It's kind of like you're saving and loading from a file and you know the name of the "file" from your GUID variable so you can find the "file" even after restarting.

Comment: If you turn a device off, it may go into hibernation and the runtime store may remain intact.  however a device reset (ex. pulling the battery) will empty the runtime store.

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry OS's 5 and newer have SQLite built in.  You can use that instead of the persistent store.  (It has a jdbc-like API).  BBOS 5 has been out for quite some time now.